# Static methods in C++

Tags: c++, private

What is the meaning of a static method in C++?
As I understand it's the same as in Java: there is no need to create an instance of the class in order to call the static method.
As I remember, in C we used static declaration for methods in order to make them private.
How do I make private methods in C++?
Let's say I want to calculate some calculation with a helper function:

```
class A{ 
  foo();
};

A::foo(){
    int a=doSomCalculations();
}
```

How would I define doSomecalculations so it will be as if private helper method as in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, if you don't *explicitly* state that something is `public`, it will be `private` by default.  So if you want `foo()` to be `public` in your class, you need to state it so.

```
class A{ 
public:
  foo();
private:
  void doSomCalulations();
};

A::foo(){
    int a=doSomCalculations();
}
```

As a comment on your C `static` thing, I don't know of anything saying that `static` makes anything `private` in C.  C has no notion of `private` and `public`.  In C you only have `struct` types, and these are all `public` by default.

In C++ `struct` have all members `public` by default. If you want a `private` member in a `struct`, you have to explicitly state it, like so:

```
struct my_struct
{
int some_public_member;

private:
int my_private_member;
};
```

OTOH, there is `static` in C which means `internal linkage`.  Perhaps you were referring to it like this.

Comment: how about if it was in a `struct`? ;)

Comment: @Nim added some data to my answer

Answer (score 1):

As you said, a static method doesn't require you to have an instance of the object.
The method is shared between the instances of that object.
In C++ you can declare a private method in the following way:

```
class YourClass { 
  public:
  void publicMethod();
  private:
  void privateMethod();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you are getting 'static' at the file scope confused with 'private' in a class context.

In order for a method or data item in a class to be private, just put it in the 'private' rather than the public section of the class, this

```
class Foo
{
   private:
     int dosomething();
   public:
     Foo();
};
```

then dosomething() can only be called within methods in Foo. A static function

```
   class Foo { public: static wibble(); }
```

would be like the Java satic function, in that you can call Foo::wibble() without having a Foo instance.

I believe using static at a filescope is deprecated, and one is encouraged to use the anonymous namespace instead.

```
  static int iamrunninoutofnames() { .... }
```

is global to the file in which it is declared, but not available outside that file.

```
 namespace { int iamrunninoutofnames() { .... } }
```

is similar in effect, but can be more flexible if you use it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

static int doSomCalculations()
{
   ...
}

(I can't check it here).

Comment: Can I ask why this solution is downgraded? It's similar to somebody elses answer who elaborated a bit more.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps because you didn't elaborate more?

Comment: Thank you, I am quite new to stackoverflow, so I will spend a bit more time to my answers in the future.